# Why every time I open the bitbook it auto quits

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

Every time I open the bitbook in Tiny Tower it auto quits. Does anyone know why and can help me solve it?

I am using a ipod touch 5th gen, running ios 6.0.2(latest).

Answer (score 4):

Check the App Store to make sure you are running the latest version of Tiny Tower.  If that doesn't do it, re-start the iPhone by holding the power button, and then Sliding to Power Off.